# How to fetch chunks of HIVE (HDFS) data, ensuring each chunk is distinct

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I have a massive dataset in HDFS. I need to process the data in chunks.

Is it feasible to first determine the **number of rows** in the full dataset using **SQL**:

```
select count(*) from my_table;
```

...then break that number into intervals using **Python**?

```
def intervals(parts, duration):
    part_duration = duration / parts
    return [(i * round(part_duration), (i + 1) * round(part_duration)) for i in range(parts)]
```

For example, if I have a million total rows:

```
intervals(3, 1000000)
```

this gives...

```
[(0, 333333), (333333, 666666), (666666, 999999)]
```

Could I then fetch these specific row numbers using **SQL**?

**EXAMPLE INPUT**:

```
row     Col1      Col2.    Col3
 1        a         b        c
 2        a         b        c
 3        a         b        c
 4        a         b        c
 5        a         b        c
 6        a         b        c
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

Returned chunk 1:

```
row     Col1     Col2    Col3
 1       a         b       c
 2       a         b       c
```

Returned chunk 2:

```
row     Col1     Col2    Col3
 3       a         b       c
 4       a         b       c
```

Returned chunk 3:

```
row     Col1     Col2    Col3
 5       a         b       c
 6       a         b       c
```

I'm not sure **HIVE** can fetch specific row numbers, and ensure the chunks are truly distinct, based on the way HDFS partitions the data. Is there some way to **ensure each chunk returned is unique, so that I can process on each chunk**?

Comment: It is not clear What is the input dataset and desired result? Please provide some example

Comment: Just chunks of rows. See updated question. The point is I need to do processing on each chunk. I just need to know that each returned chunk is different than every other returned chunk.

Comment: Normally this is solved by setting some range to be an [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) which should probably be your `id` column in this case. This problem may also be a good fit for [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Comment: Dash is for running in-memory. The point here is my data are too large to fit in memory, which is why I must fetch individual chunks from Hive. So my query must be aware of some indexed column that is Hive is aware of, to ensure each chunk is unique. I guess this has to already be in place in the Hive tables

Comment: It is still unclear. All rows in the input are equal except id. So chunks are determined only by id, right? same ids should be eliminated before chunks calculation? right? How are you going to use it really?  will it be enough just to have chunk number calculated? Multiple outputs are confusing. Chunks are pair of rows with consecutive ids starting from the lowest one, right?

Comment: Hive is parallel processing tool. And if you have splittable file, like CSV or ORC or JSON text file, it will be splitted and processed in parallel in different mappers normally. Usage scenario is not clear